# How to count matches using compare + je?

Tags: assembly, x86, predicate

I am writing a code that counts how many words are in a string. How can I increase a register using je?

For example:

```
cmp a[bx+1],00h
je inc cx
```

Answer (score 5):

[`je`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) is a conditional *jump*.  Unlike ARM, x86 can't directly predicate another single instruction based on an arbitrary condition.  There's no single machine instruction that can do anything like `je inc cx` or ARM-style `inceq cx`.

Instead you need to build the logic yourself by conditionally branching over other instruction(s).

---

If you want to increase a register if two numbers compare equal, try something like this:

```
        cmp a[bx + 1], 00h  ; compare numbers
        jne .noteq          ; if they are different, skip
        inc cx              ; the increment
.noteq:
```

A branch-free option is possible if you have a 386-compatible CPU.  It requires an extra register:

```
        xor ax, ax          ; clear register
        cmp a[bx + 1], 00h  ; compare numbers
        sete al             ; set al = 1 if the numbers are equal
        add cx, ax          ; increment cx if numbers are equal
```

---

PPro compatible CPUs have [`cmovcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMOVcc.html) and [`fcmovcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FCMOVcc.html).  Along with [`setcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html) (386), [`jcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) (8086), and [`loopcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html) (8086), those are x86's only condition-checking instructions.  (Conditions bits are stored in the FLAGS register where you could access them directly, but usually that's less convenient.)